# Change fortify .NST file Generation Location

Tags: fortify

Currently, the .NST files after build are getting generated at "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Fortify\sca6.2\build" folder. How can I change the it to some other folder in my system?

Answer (score 2):

There are two files that need to be updated, located in the /Core/config:

- fortify.properties

  - com.fortify.WorkingDirectory=${win32.LocalAppdata}/Fortify
- fortify-sca.properties

  - com.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=${win32.LocalAppdata}/Fortify

If you are also using the Eclipse plugin, make sure to change the files inside of there as well:

- \plugins\com.fortify.dev.ide.eclipse_X.XX.X\Core\config\fortify.properties"

Make sure that fortify will have permissions to read/write to the new target location.  Depending on how locked down your environment is (permissions, GPs) this could be tricky.

Update:

If you wanted to change a setting for once scan and/or cannot update the properties files, you can update the properties through commandline arguments.

You would need to pass these arguments on all commands to sourceanalyzer to work (clean, translate, and scan).

For any propertie that needs to change, you pass the following in the command:

- `-D<property>=<value>`

In this case (assuming you want to put the working directory `D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory`):

- `-Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory"`

Here is the batch file I used to scan the EightBall.java example file (normally located at `<fortify Install Dir>\Samples\Basic\EightBall\` and moved it to `D:\Samples\EightBall\`

```
# Clean
sourceanalyzer -b eightball -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -clean

# Translate
sourceanalyzer -b eightball -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -source 1.5 EightBall.java

# Scan
sourceanalyzer -b eightball -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot="D:\Samples\eightball\working Directory" -scan -f EightBall.fpr
```

Comment: Hi SBurris, so here the challenge in above approach - I cannot modify properties files. I am trying to set WorkingDirectory and ProjectRoot through command line for a particular fortify scan: set com.fortify.WorkingDirectory=C:\Users\<name>\Downloads set com.fortify.ProjectRoot=C:\Users\<name>\Downloads                              and it didn't work. How can I change these parameters without actually modifying the properties files.